# Type 'number' has no properties in common with type 'XrangePointOptionsObject'

Tags: highcharts, angular9, angular-highcharts

I'm getting this error Type 'number' has no properties in common with type 'XrangePointOptionsObject'. I want to add a bar chart using angular highchatrs in my angular project but I'm not able to add because of this error. So can you please help me to solve this error. 
Please help me solve this error.

Thanks

```
import { Component, Optional, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Chart } from 'angular-highcharts';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-graphical',
  templateUrl: './graphical.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./graphical.component.scss']
})
export class GraphicalComponent implements OnInit {

  orderChart: Chart;
  revenueChart: Chart;
  options: Highcharts.Options;

  chartData: any[]= [];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    this.options = {
      chart: {
         type: 'column'
      },
      title: {
         text: 'Total Predected Vs Actual'
      },
      xAxis:{
         categories: ['2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017'],
         crosshair: true        
      },     
      yAxis : {
         min: 0 ,

      },
      tooltip : {
         headerFormat: '<span style = "font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
         pointFormat: '<tr><td style = "color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style = "padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>', footerFormat: '</table>', shared: true, useHTML: true
      },
      plotOptions : {
         column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
         }
      },
      series: [
         {
            name: "Predected",
            data :[14,17,9,10,6,19,6,8]
         },
         {
            name: "Actual",
            data: [65,74,44,66,9,23,36,51]
         }
         ]
    };
    let orderChart = new Chart(this.options);
    this.orderChart = orderChart;

    let revenueChart = new Chart(this.options);
    this.revenueChart = revenueChart;
  }

}
```

Please help me to solve this error